# Puppet-enterprise-install fails basename: missing operand

Tags: puppet

I just downloaded the puppet enterprise installer for my OS version from the [puppetlabs website](https://puppetlabs.com/download-puppet-enterprise-welcome) and the installer seems to fail immediately. Why is it failing:

```
sudo ./puppet-enterprise-installer
basename: missing operand
Try `basename --help' for more information.
```

This is the only output from the installer before it stops.

I am running Centos 6 64bit.

Comment: That looks like a bug. That's why I was asking whether you downloaded from their site. That error means that `basename` was run with no target but we can't help without having access to the script you're running.

Comment: Installer script: http://pastebin.com/4arN31WJ

Comment: OK, that makes no sense. The only `basename` call there is run on `$0` which can't ever be empty (it's the name of the running script) as far as I know. Try creating a file with this line: `basename ${0?}`, save it as `foo` and then run `/bin/bash foo`. Does that also give an error?

Comment: No error, just outputs "foo"

Comment: Please run `sudo bash -x ./puppet-enterprise-installer` and post the resulting trace.

Comment: trace: http://pastie.org/private/lunpthoxwz0m05fkkeoknq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue (centos 6 64 bit). I found some of the system packages missing. I got through by running:

`yum install -y pciutils system-logos which libxml2 dmidecode net-tools virt-what apr apr-util curl mailcap libjpeg libtool-ltdl unixODBC libxslt zlib`

make sure you have the dependencies installed. See - 
https://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/install_system_requirements.html